# Using HTML, CSS, JS with Python to make desktop application?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I recently made a program. It's developed using Node.JS and Electron to make it a desktop application. Unfortunately, Electron is quite big in base file size and I'd like to reduce the file size. I've looked at my app files before adding electron and it's around 38mb. When adding electron it's roughly over 100mb more than the original.

I've been looking into converting the program to Python to hopefully reduce the size of it. Though I only know the basics of Python such as how to declare variables and functions. I've seen stuff like Tkinter and stuff, but would I be able to use HTML, CSS, JS to make the UI of the program and use Python as the back bone(i.e. using materailizecss framework for the ui).

If so, how could I do this? Also, to make it clear, I don't want a web app, I'm looking for a desktop application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES. You can use QT standard library but if you persist on writing UI yourself there is an HTMLpy Library which can find here [HTMLPY](http://amol-mandhane.github.io/htmlPy/)

htmlPy is a wrapper around PySide's QtWebKit library. It helps with creating beautiful GUIs using HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript for standalone Python applications.

go through it and you will find interesting things